# Prevent script from reloading again

Tags: jquery, json

I've made a script like an infinite loading script. Everything works fine when you scroll from top to bottom. Things go wrong when I click a product and hit the browser back button to go back to the page with the infinite loader. All products are loaded again.

After some searching I found this *could* be bevause of the `document.ready` function is triggered again. Problem is that all other scripts aren't working anymore. 
My next own suggestion was to empty the div where the products are loaded in before they are loaded. Problem now is that only the first or last product of the next page is loaded.

Does anyone know a solution or maybe can point me to some directions?

My full loader script ->

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var currentPage = {{ collection.page }};
  var collectionPages = {{ collection.pages }};
  var category = '{{ collection.internal.url }}';

  var appendProduct = function(product) {
    if(currentPage == 1){
      return false
    }
        //$(".collection-more").html("");
    $('<div class="product"></div>').html(product).appendTo($(".collection-more"));  
    var i = 1;
    $('.product').each(function() {
      if(i++ % 3 == 0)
        $(this).addClass('last');
    });
  };

  var loadProducts = function() {

    var url = "http://www.hioshop.nl/"+category+"/page"+currentPage+".ajax";

    $.getJSON(url,function(data) {

      $.each(data.products, function(index, product) {

        var imageUrl = product.image.replace('50x50x2', '180x150x2');

        var itemHtml = '' +
            '<a href="' + product.url + '" title="'+ product.fulltitle +'"><img src="'+imageUrl+'" width="180" height="150" alt="'+product.fulltitle+'" title="'+product.fulltitle+'" />';

        if(product.data_01 === 'sale'){
          itemHtml = itemHtml + '<div class="labels sale"></div>';
        }
        if(product.data_01 === 'nieuw'){
          itemHtml = itemHtml + '<div class="labels nieuw"></div>';
        }
        itemHtml = itemHtml +   
            '</a>' +
            '<div class="info">' +
            '<h3>' + '<a href="' + product.url + '" title="'+ product.fulltitle +'">' + product.fulltitle + '</a>' + '</h3>' +
            '<div class="price">' + product.price.price_money + '';

        if(product.price.price_old){
          itemHtml = itemHtml + ' <span>' + '<del>' + product.price.price_old_money + '</del>' + '</span>';
        }    

        itemHtml = itemHtml +
          '</div>' + // price
          '<div class="gridAddToCart">' +
          '<a class="button grey" href="'+product.url+'" title="'+product.fulltitle+'" rel="nofollow">'+'<span>Details</span></a>' +
          '<div style="margin-top:2px;"></div>' +
          '<a class="opener button blue" href="{{ 'cart/add/' | url }}'+product.vid+'" title="'+product.fulltitle+'" rel="nofollow"><span>In winkelwagen</span></a>'

          itemHtml = itemHtml +
          '</div>' + // gridAddToCart
          '</div>' + // info
          '<div class="clear"></div>' +
          '</div>';

        appendProduct(itemHtml)
          });

        $("#overlay").fadeOut();

        $(window).scroll(function() {
          update();
        });

      });
    };

    loadProducts();

    var isUpdating = false;

    var update = function() {  

      if($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - 2000) {

        if(currentPage < collectionPages && !isUpdating) {

          isUpdating = true;

          currentPage++;
            $("#overlay").fadeIn();
          $(window).unbind('scroll');  


          setTimeout(function(){

            loadProducts();

            setTimeout(function(){

              isUpdating = false;

            }, 100);

          }, 100);
        }
      }
    };

    $(window).scroll(function() {
      update();
    });


</script>
```

**UPDATED** Complete code

Comment: Try posting a stripped down version of your code. You've got lots of things in there that we all don't need to know about. Perhaps break it down to just an alert or a console.log.

Comment: @SimonHartigan: Ok will do that! Thx

Comment: @SimonHartigan: Ok I've deleted the json part. Why I posted the whole code is because I don't really know where the problem could be :(

Comment: Reloading a page shouldn't cause all portions to be loaded again. Unless going back saved where it was on the y-axis in the browser and that caused the script to run again. I can't think of anything else based on the provided code.

Comment: @SimonHartigan; Well when the back button is hit the script returns to the previous place (eg. middle of page 2). From there it starts loading again. Do you have a suggestion to fix that issue? I've never heard of your suggestion! Thx

Comment: @SimonHartigan: In the console log I see that when I hit the back button the pages are just loaded once. The products are still showed twice. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @SimonHartigan: What exactly do you mean with "upload your vote"? Upload the whole script? Or just +1 for your help?

Comment: Can you upload your code so I can inspect it?

Comment: @zeMinimalist: Sorry for the late reply but I was away from a computer. I've updated the post with the complete script!

Comment: I meant upload to the internet so I can see the html and css in action as well.

Comment: @zeMinimalist: Ok sorry... ;) you can see it in action here: hioshop.nl/slaapkamer/

Comment: Excellent, this helps a lot (fyi for the future). What browser and operating system are you using? It looks fine on a Mac with Safari. It remembers where it was on the page before, which is good, and has cached everything. I'd say this is good user experience.

Comment: @zeMinimalist: Ok thx for watching.... Problem is that when you click a product somewhere halfway, hit the browser back button and you'll see that the products from page 1 are loaded again!

Comment: @zeMinimalist: FYI I'm using firefox... could this be a cache problem?

Comment: I just checked Firefox on Windows and see how it's kind of glitchy. However, I'm confused as to what you want. Trying to force the page to load up top would be a bad user experience and trying to fight what the browser does natively, and not loading all the images would also be bad potentially. Anything shy of updating the url with the html5 pushstate so you include a hash tag, and then when a page is loaded with a hash tag do something special. I'm not sure what to tell you. Consider this a problem when using infinite scroll.